# ExtJS + Spring: Unable to receive PDF in browser after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring, extjs, pdf-generation, itext

I am using Spring + ExtJS and need to 'export to' functionality on UI screen. I am making an Ajax call and sending the data in JSON format to controller. In controller I am doing all stuff to generate the PDF using iText and it does generate the document.

Now I am not seeing the generated PDF to downlaod/view in browser. If I do it without Ajax call, it works. Not sure whats making the difference.

I read few related articles around this which suggested to use below :

```
Content-type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FileName.pdf"
```

But no luck with this. Please advice on this/let me know if going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265406-Download-file-using-javascript-extjs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery), you can use an hidden iframe to do this.
Personnally I prefer the hidden form posting solution, here is an example :

```
var formEl = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
            tag: 'form',
            css : 'display:none;',
            id: 'downloadForm'
        }, true);
var form = new Ext.form.BasicForm(formEl, {
            url : [your spring controller url],
            method : 'POST',
            fileUpload: true,
            baseParams: [your JSON parameters]|| {}
        });
form.doAction(new Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit({
            form: form,
            clientValidation: false
        }));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using iFrame is not supposed to be done in my project, more over, it doesnt work when tried. :(

Comment: Did you try storing the PDF first locally on server and then sending that location info in ajax reponse and then fetching the file later the ajax request ?